# how find manufacturer of my memory?

Tags: java, windows, memory, terminal, command

I tried to find out what the manufacturer of my memory and have not had much success. 
Does someone could help me figure this out, using a java command or a command terminal, in case I want to find this in Windows, because Linux already managed to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From windows CMD use following command,

```
wmic MemoryChip get Manufacturer
```